# Stickers customization to add an image as an overlay to another image using PESDK on android

Tags: android, ios, photoeditorsdk

I am looking for the solution to be able to put an image from the file system above original image using PESDK for android and ios. As I see there is no such functionality supported by PESDK by default, but Stickers functionality looks very similar to what I need.
So, I tried customizing stickers behavior. The idea is to provide custom stickers list using the images from the file system and creating custom ImageStickerConfig with appropriate preview and image sources.

The first problem I faced is OutOfMemory exception happening on stickers list screen. It happens when I provide preview source equal to the image source(stickers list does not do images downscaling).

The second problem is a crash happening when some not readable(broken) image is provided as a preview source. I can provide crash log is needed.

Based on the story above I have the following questions:

1. Is there any other way to add an image as an overlay to another image than customising Stickers behavior?
2. Can I expect that preview images downscaling will be supported? The workaround to store thumbnails for all the images in a filesystem is not good from the performance perspective.
3. Can I expect broken images to be handled in an appropriate way by the SDK?

Thanks in advance

Edit 16.01.2018, answering to Sven Nähler questions:

2. Unfortunately, I continue getting OOM error even after the ImageStickerConfig was extended. The device is LG g3s, android 5.1. Log:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
                                                                     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
                                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
                                                                     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:649)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.system.NativeSupportedDecoder.decodeAsBitmap(NativeSupportedDecoder.java:88)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.RasterDecoder.getBitmap(RasterDecoder.java:53)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.ImageSource.getBitmap(ImageSource.java:389)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.ImageSource.getBitmap(ImageSource.java:376)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.createThumbnailBitmap(AbstractConfig.java:195)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.getThumbnailBitmap(AbstractConfig.java:189)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.getThumbnailBitmap(AbstractConfig.java:173)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.generateBindDataAsync(AbstractConfig.java:128)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.generateBindDataAsync(AbstractConfig.java:34)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.ui.adapter.DataSourceListAdapter$LoaderList.runEntryProcess(DataSourceListAdapter.java:381)
                                                                     at ly.img.android.ui.adapter.DataSourceListAdapter$LoaderList$Task.run(DataSourceListAdapter.java:416)

3. The log is below:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1047)
                                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1033)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.vector.XmlDrawableDecoder.getDrawable(XmlDrawableDecoder.java:204)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.vector.XmlDrawableDecoder.decodeSize(XmlDrawableDecoder.java:84)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.Decoder.getSize(Decoder.java:181)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.VectorDecoder.calculateExactSample(VectorDecoder.java:110)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.VectorDecoder.getBitmap(VectorDecoder.java:62)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.ImageSource.getBitmap(ImageSource.java:389)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.decoder.ImageSource.getBitmap(ImageSource.java:376)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.createThumbnailBitmap(AbstractConfig.java:195)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.getThumbnailBitmap(AbstractConfig.java:189)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.getThumbnailBitmap(AbstractConfig.java:173)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.generateBindDataAsync(AbstractConfig.java:128)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.sdk.models.config.AbstractConfig.generateBindDataAsync(AbstractConfig.java:34)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.ui.adapter.DataSourceListAdapter$LoaderList.runEntryProcess(DataSourceListAdapter.java:381)
                                                                   at ly.img.android.ui.adapter.DataSourceListAdapter$LoaderList$Task.run(DataSourceListAdapter.java:416)

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not really sure, what you are trying to, can you explain what are you mean by "as Overlay"? Did you mean Blendmodes?

   2. The SDK does not downscale by default so you have to extend the ImageStickerConfig class, and override this two methods

      @Override
      public boolean hasStaticThumbnail() {
              return false;
      }

      @Nullable
      public Bitmap getThumbnailBitmap() {
              int maxWidth  = Math.round(PESDK.getAppResource().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity * 56);
              int maxHeight = Math.round(PESDK.getAppResource().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity * 56);
              ImageSource imageSource = getThumbnailSource();
              Bitmap preview = imageSource != null ? imageSource.getBitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight, true) : null;
              return preview != null ? preview : BitmapFactoryUtils.NOTING_BITMAP;
      }

This will load the image downscaled into the memory to prevent the OutOfMemory Exception.

3. Sure, a broken images should not cause a crash. Can you give us the crash log, please? Maybe it is a bug.

Best,
Sven

Comment: 1. I'm trying to put an image from the gallery above the image that is being edited. The same as Stickers tool does, but stickers are actually images from the gallery.

Comment: 2 and 3 - I edited original question to provide logs as comments have characters limit

Comment: 1. After extending the ImageStickerConfig, did you create your "gallery" Sticker config from it?
I mean, instead of "new ImageStickerConfig(...)" create form your extended class like "new MyImageStickerConfig(...)"

2. If you also use a gallery image for the StickerCategory, did you extend the `StickerCategoryConfig` also?

3. The crash seems to be strange because the SDK has detected that the image is a VectorDrawable. 

Is it possible that you create an example project and share it with us?

Comment: 1. Yes, I did it

Comment: 2. No, can it affect anything?

Comment: 3. Here you can find test project with the functionality we are trying to develop https://drive.google.com/file/d/14FODORdGaLlC3NZubxtD86j2MsHUkMNE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Regarding 3 - I've found the cause of the crash. The issue is with 0 bytes files which the sdk cannot handle in correct way and tries to work with it as with vector drawable. I am able to avoid it on my side and it is up to you to fix or not to fiz that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your extended class "PBImageStickerConfig", do not have a parcable "CREATOR".
So android uses the "CREATOR" of the default "ImageStickerConfig" class. This results in ignoring your implementation and creates a normal "ImageStickerConfig".

```
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    }

    protected PBImageStickerConfig(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public static final Creator<PBImageStickerConfig> CREATOR = new Creator<PBImageStickerConfig>() {
        @Override
        public PBImageStickerConfig createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new PBImageStickerConfig(source);
        }

        @Override
        public PBImageStickerConfig[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PBImageStickerConfig[size];
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, I applied these changes. Still, OOM exception happens. I have around 200 images in a gallery.

Comment: Could you please describe the way sdk stores the thumbnails and handles memory for them? As I see they all are stored in memory without any kind of lazy loading or caching mechanism which makes memory resources free if it is needed. Please correct me if I am wrong